# Order of unitriangular matrix

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I have unitriangular matrix group over a field $F_q$.
It consists of the following elements:
$$E + A = \left[\begin{matrix}
    1 & a12 & ... & a1n\\
    0 & 1 & a23 & ...\\
    ... & ... & ... & ... \\
    0 & 0 & ... & 1\\
    \end{matrix}\right]$$  $E$ is identity matrix.

I have to prove that minimum $m$: $(E+A)^{m}=E$, has a form $p^l, l <= n-1$.

In other words, prove that order of matrix $(E+A)$ has a form of $p^l, l <= n-1$.

And also find matrix with maximum order $p^{n-1}$.

So far, I know that $(E+A)^{p^{n-1}}=E$ and that $A^{n-1}=0$, but have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the order of the group? [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) could be useful to show that the order of $E+A$ is of the form $p^l$.